# Can Jekyll use other file formats apart from markdown?

Tags: jekyll

I have a large quantity of HTML files can i use these and turn them into blog posts??

I am trying to work out a way to turn these into blog posts, and i am not sure if Jekyll is the right option.

Answer (score 1):

Given your original post `post-title.html` is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Intro</h2>
    <p>Text here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You just keep the content part :

```
<h2>Intro</h2>
<p>Text here</p>
```

Add a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) to it :

```
---
layout: post
---
<h2>Intro</h2>
<p>Text here</p>
```

Rename it to `2014-12-21-post-title.html`. And you're good to go ! Jekyll post can be markdown, but html too !

Note : the title (`page.title`) is here derived from the file name. If you want to use an elaborated title, you can add it in the front matter :

```
---
...
title: I'm a blogger, sometimes !!
---
```

Useful informations can be found in [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/).